# wor2vec() in R is producing different embedding over repetition even after using same seed via set.seed()

Tags: word2vec, reproducible-research

wor2vec() in R is producing different embedding over repetition even after using same seed via set.seed(). I am using R 3.6.1 and tried with RNGversion("3.6.1") before set.seed() but still different result. Need help.
Code snippet:
word2vec_model <- word2vec(evets,type="cbow",dim=embd_dim,iter=5L,hs=TRUE,min_count = 1,split=c(','))
sample of event
str(test_tokens_evets)
chr [1:13] "event_1,event_2,event_2,event_3,event_1,event_4"| **truncated** ...